# select table names from MySQL as a file to HDFS

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

In MySQL database I have 100 tables. Some of the table names end similarly like below

```
123_testing
124_testing
125_testing_10
and so on
```

Now I want to select the tables that end like `_testing` and have the results as a file in hdfs.

I want to sqoop the table names as a file to HDFS.

How can we do that.

I can use `sqoop list-tables` but it gives me results of all table and on the local machine. We cannot specify `--target-dir` option with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list-tables` does not accept `--target-dir` argument.

The table names are available in the `information_schema` database of MySQL. This query will fetch the tables in `db_name` that end like `_testing`.

```
select TABLE_NAME from TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA='db_name' and TABLE_NAME like '%_testing';
```

Use this query with `--query` argument in `sqoop-import` and then use the `--target-dir`.